# NetworkX - how is Graph.nodes() able to take in parameters?

Tags: python, networkx

When I look at the code for Graph.nodes() here: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/classes/graph.py#L658 it doesn't take in any parameters. So how is it that I am able to pass something like data=True (e.g., Graph.nodes(data=True))? Ideally, I would get a "got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'" error.

It is also decorated as a property, but I am able to call it as a function. This is probably a basic python question, but this is the first time I am encountering this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping `networkx` aside. Take this code snippet.

```
class CallableIterable:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val[:]

    def __call__(self, arg1=True):
        print('acting as a callable')
        return f'You called this with {arg1}'

    def __contains__(self, arg):
        print('acting as an iterable')
        return arg in self.val

class Graph:
    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return CallableIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You can see that there are two classes `CallableIterable` and `Graph`. `Graph` has a property `nodes` that returns an instance of `CallableIterable` when called.

Create an instance of `Graph` `g`.

`g = Graph()`

Now you can use the property `g.nodes` in two ways.

**As an iterable**

`print(1 in g.nodes)`

This gives

```
acting as an iterable
True
```

This is because `in` triggers the `__contains__` method of the `CallableIterable` class (in this example).

**As a callable**

`print(g.nodes('some random value'))`

This gives

```
acting as a callable
You called this with some random value
```

This is because it triggers the `__call__` method of the `CallableIterable` class.

The arguments passed in `()`, in this case, `'some random value'` of `g.nodes('some random value')` or in your case, `data=True` of `Graph().nodes(data=True)` are passed to the **`__call__` of the return value of the property** `(which is g.nodes)`, **NOT TO** the property decorated function `Graph.nodes`.

Internally this is `g.nodes.__call__('some random value')`.

With this understanding apply the same principle to `networkx`, where `NodeView` is the type of object returned instead of the `CallableIterable` as seen in this example, the working is the same.

1. [`nodes = NodeView(self)`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/classes/graph.py#L748) is an instance of the [`NodeView`
   class](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/classes/reportviews.py#L115).
2. This class has a [`__call__`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/classes/reportviews.py#L204) and a [`__contains__`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d70b314b37168f0ea7c5b0d7f9ff61d73232747b/networkx/classes/reportviews.py#L196) method.
3. Which lets you use it as a callable / function
   (`Graph().nodes(data=True))`) and as an iterable (`'something' in Graph().nodes`).

The `NodeView` class has other functions than just `__call__` and `__contains__`, each of which will get called appropriately.

This is essentially what the docstrings mean with the following

> ```
>     Can be used as `G.nodes` for data lookup and for set-like operations.
>     Can also be used as `G.nodes(data='color', default=None)` to return a
>     NodeDataView which reports specific node data but no set operations
> ```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed explanation with an example. It's amazing how powerful Python is, but can also be used in very hard to understand ways. Not sure why they needed to use it so.

Comment: glad I could be of help :D, if you want to know more about this look into (when you feel more comfortable with python) https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html an everyday user can get away with not knowing this though